# String.substring not returning true

Tags: c++, string, arduino

I'm working on an Arduino and String.substring does not appear to be operating correctly, so I'm wondering what I may be doing wrong....

My function is as follows:

```
boolean processSerial()
{
     String buf;
     int iter = 0;
     char thisChar; 

     while(iter < 1000){
     if (Serial.available()) {
       #if ARDUINO >= 100 //For Arduino v1.0+
       {
         thisChar = Serial.read();
         buf += thisChar;
         //if(DEBUG){Serial.print(thisChar);}
       }  
       #else //For Arduino v0023 or earlier
         thisChar = Serial.read();
       #endif
     }
     iter++;
     }
     Serial.print(buf);
     Serial.print(buf.substring(0,10));

     if(buf.substring(1) == "GPGGA"){
        Serial.println("FOUND IT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        }
        Serial.println("And we're done");

}
```

The pattern "GPGGA" is coming up but substring is not returning true.

The output from my Serial is as follows:

```
$GPGGA,053540.000,3804.1237,N,07615.5232,W,1,7,1.39,117.5,M,-33$GPGGA,053And we're done
```

Thus `buf` clearly has 'GPGGA' in the string.  The last little bit that shows 'GPGGA' again is the printing of charcters 0-10 in the string.  Why is my `if` statement not returning true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`buf.substring(1)` returns the substring starting at position one and continuing all the way to the end of the string. This will start with `GPGGA`, but it will not *equal* `GPGGA`.

If you know the string you compare to is 5 characters in length, you could use

```
if (buf.substring(1,1+5) == "GPGGA")
  /* ... */
```

Also note that it's not the `substring()` function that is expected to return true, but the comparison operator `==`.

Comment: Hmm, so how do I search for that pattern 'within the first 10 characters'?

Comment: Also, your statement conflicts with this documentation.  Wonder why they are wrong... http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringSubstring

Comment: My statement was correct, but to make it work, you actually need `(1,1+5)`, because this `substring` function, unlike the `std::string::substring()` function accepts the end position as second argument, not the length as I had originally assumed.

Comment: Thanks very much!  Think I had a little bit of writers block late at night... :)